# A custom date picker that only goes to 1997

Tags: jquery

I have a Jfiddle of a j-query date picker.

I'm having some trouble making the year stop at 1997, the year of the tiger.

Could somebody help me rejigger it for Tigger.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgk8x0mo/

---

Jquery

```
$('#datePick').datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(1997, 2 - 1, 1),
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
```

---

html

```
<input id="datePick" />
```

Comment: You've set `minDate` to 1997 and it appears to be working fine. Do you mean you want the `maxDate` instead?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want 1997 as the earliest year you can choose and the latest date as something like 1940

Comment: @SprigMendle I think you have that the wrong way round surely?  The latest would be 1997 and the earliest would be 1940?

Answer (score 1):

> i want 1997 as the earliest year you can choose and the minDate as 1940

Assuming you mean that 1997 should be the latest year (given that 1940 is earlier than 1997), you just need to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` values accordingly:

```
$('#datePick').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(1940, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(1997, 0, 1),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```